# can't use certificates installed in the store as server-side certificates

Tags: c#, uwp, ssl-certificate

I'm developing an application in UWP which acts as a server and i made a self-signed certificate and installed it on both the server and client, I checked the certificate if it has a private key and it does, and when I retrieve it from the store programmatically it loads the private key, but for some reason when the authentication handshake starts the server says that "the credentials supplied to the package were not recognized", the only way it works is when I get the certificate as a PFX from a folder...

this one works:

```
Selectedcert = new X509Certificate2("LocalCertificate.pfx","password", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
```

this doesn't:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection cers = 
store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "localhost", false);
X509Certificate2 Selectedcert = null;
foreach (var c in cers)
   if (c.HasPrivateKey && c.PrivateKey != null)
       Selectedcert = c;
```

I checked the manifest and the application has Capabilities to the Shared User Certificates also I checked the certificate permissions and the user does have permissions to read the private-key

Edit:

- also i have Tried both StoreName.My and StoreName.Root

i tried the same code in a console application and the authentication handshake is ok, so the problem is with the UWP restrictions, it doesn't let the application to use the private key or something like that
i dont know how to get an X509Cert in UWP if someone knows please inform me, thank you :)

Comment: If you intend to use the private key, I'm pretty sure you need to install the certificate in `StoreName.My`.

Comment: @Xerillio its already installed in there, also i tried StoreName.My but still have the problem

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine when I try with `StoreName.My`. Are you running the application as the same user?

Comment: @Xerillio yea, i only have one user, im not sure if this problem is caused because of UWP or not, i'll try to make console application to test it and will notify you about the results :)

Comment: @Xerillio ok, so i tried the same code in a console application and the authentication handshake is ok, so the problem is with the UWP restrictions, it doesn't let the application to get the private key it seems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that UWP apps are running in the sandbox so that it has limitations when trying to accessing the localhost. So in your scenario, you could not get the certificates.

**Update:**

The sharedUserCertificates works for UWP APIs like [UserCertificateStore Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.usercertificatestore?view=winrt-19041) and [CertificateStores Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores?view=winrt-19041). You could check the official sample -[UserCertificateStore](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserCertificateStore) to see how these APIs could get the certificates from the certificates store.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that this is a bug in the platform or there is another API that i'm not aware of, because you can give permission to your app to access the certificate store and its called "Shared user certificates" more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations, which i already done that, i tried to access the certificates without adding that capability and i couldn't receive any certificates, but when i added that capability i received the certificates but couldn't use them as server side certificates...

Comment: The sharedUserCertificates works for UWP APIs like [UserCertificateStore Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.usercertificatestore?view=winrt-19041) and [CertificateStores Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores?view=winrt-19041). You could check the official sample -[UserCertificateStore](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserCertificateStore) to see how these APIs could get the certificates from the certificates store.

Comment: So the behavior you got is by design.

Comment: please add that to your original answer, i'll accept it and thank you :D

Comment: also is it possible to change the Certificate to x509? i cant find anything like that online, because the sslStream only accepts x509 certificates...

Comment: I haven't found a way to change the Certificate to x509 as well. So I'd suggest using the first way- get the X509Cert directly from the file. Another way which is a little bit harder is that you could enumerate all the certificates in the store like `foreach (var certificate in store.Certificates)` to check for the one you needed.